What’s cutting off the leaves on my broccoli?
My broccoli is in a raised bed and the plants are covered by a net.
In a single night they have all had their leaves cut off leaving just stalks.  Very clean cuts almost like scissors.  The bed is three feet high and galvanized steel so not likely rabbits.

How long is the piece of string I have?  Its white.  3mm thick - Answer is the same to both questions.

Rats, Rabbits, Possums....  Please post a photo

Cut off, or cut off and eaten/removed? Anyway, something that gets under the net, so usually rodent-ish. We stopped netting blueberries because we lost more to ground-dwelling rodents emboldened by protective netting than we did to the mixture of rodents and birds without netting.

See https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/63521/6806 for "how to find out given when we live."
